# Calling a function inside an initializer list with an empty parameter pack function argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have

```
void foo(double &arg, uint8_t *data)
{
    // ...
}

template <class T>
void foo(T &arg, uint8_t *data)
{
    // ...
}
```

and I call it in

```
template <class ...T>
void bar(T... arg)
{
    uint8_t *data = new uint8_t[SOME_VALUE];

    // guaranteed to be executed in order
    auto list = {(foo(arg, data), 1)...};

   // ...
}
```

But it fails when bar is called with 0 arguments, because of the way `foo` is called in the initializer list.

How can I modify this to make `bar` work with an empty parameter pack? The result should be as if the initializer list has never executed.

I'd like to keep the `foo` application iterative, i.e. with the initializer list in `bar`, rather than recursive, when we do a single call to `foo` in `bar` and the variadic-template `foo` calls itself until its parameter pack is empty. (Mostly because the latter seems to be costly -- the stack falls through quite a lot when the pack has many arguments and it causes a lot of different template versions of `foo` to be generated.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the problem is that `auto list = {};` doesn't work.

Either specify the type explicitly:

```
std::initializer_list<int> list = {(foo(arg, data), 1)...};
```

or give it an extra element:

```
auto list = {1, (foo(arg, data), 1)...};
```

Side note: for fully generic code, when you don't know the return type of `foo`, you'd want to cast the return value of `foo` to `void`, to defend against possibly overloaded comma operators.

Comment: Wow, that simple. And here I was trying to find a clever way to overload `foo`, even making it a struct.

Comment: If I recall there's another trick like `using magic=int[]; magic{1,(foo(arg,data),1)...};` which makes the array an unnamed temporary, which makes it blatantly obvious to the compiler that it can be completely elided.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's somewhat orthogonal - you still need to add an extra element to handle the empty-pack case.

Comment: @T.C.: It's 100% orthogonal, sorry if I was unclear :D.  It's just another trick that can be used with this pattern.,